# Calling a function of a loop - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, loops, for-loop

So I have a function inside of an object that chooses one of the 4 exercises at random.

```
    this.lift = function (number, group) {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(number));
        const pick = group[random]
        return pick
    }
```

And then I have arrays of exercises corresponding to each group for it to pick from

```
 this.chest = ["Bench Press", "Incline Bench Press", "Weighted Dips", "Chest Fly"]
 this.back = ["Wide Grip Pulldown", "Close Grip Pulldown", "Barbell Row", "Seated/Supported Row"]

etc. etc. etc.
```

I can call the function individually to pick an exercise for each group, something like this:

```
console.log(work.lift(4, work.chest))
console.log(work.lift(4, work.back))
etc. etc.
```

But that's kinda ugly, and it would literally call this function sometimes 24+ times at once. so I want to just make it run on a nice clean loop. So I have this:

```
            const arnie = ["chest", "back", "delt", "bicep", "tricep", "quad", "ham", "core"]

            for (const muscle of arnie) {
                console.log(work.lift(4, whatgoeshere))
            }
```

And yet I cannot get it to work, have tried work.muscle, work.arnie[i] using var i in the loop, none of that runs. I must be missing something very small. So whatgoeshere?

Comment: It's `work[arnie[i]]` or - since you're not iterating with an index - just `work[muscle]`

Answer (score 2):

The `muscle` var references the muscle group, you can use it to index into `work`

```
work.lift(4, work[muscle])
```

See [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)